# Is it possible to return a set of attributes of product using rest APIs.?

Tags: product, attributes, rest-api

Is it possible to return only a set of attributes corresponding to the product by calling api/rest/products. In first stage I might not want the description to be loaded, I just needed the name, price and image url. But when I call the rest api it returns every attributes. Is it possible to restrict the attributes returned without disabling those attributes in the Roles.

Comment: Yes it is possible but need to add some custom code in catalog product rest api